# Hitting F5 in CTRLP result in == NO ENTRIES ==

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I wanted to update the content of CTRLP so I hit F5 while in the CTRLP mode but now no files shows up and instead i get == NO ENTRIES ==.

What did I do wrong and what can I do to repopulate the buffer with my pwd?

Answer (score 0):

I use the [silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) to ctrl-p my files and folders in vim (s. [this introduction](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/faster-grepping-in-vim) as a great reference). As the silver searcher respects your .gitignore-settings and because I had, by mistake, a ~/.gitignore-file excluding basically every file, I had no entries in my ctrl-p buffer.